# Javascript is incorrectly parsing variable literally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that is used to edit the css of a particular element. The element is selected through JQuery, and stored values for css retrieved from a 2D array. However, when I am setting `styles` in the code, it takes `prop` literally as `"prop"`, and not as its string value. In the debugger I see that `prop` does indeed have a valid string value, but this is not coming through when setting `styles`. I understand this is likely a syntax issue.

```
function foo(selector) {

    var element = $(selector);

    for (var prop in stylesOld[selector]) { //stylesOld is a 2D array using key / value pairs
        if (stylesOld[selector].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

            // here lies the problem
            var styles = { prop : stylesOld[selector][prop]};

            element.css(styles);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using `prop.toString()` however this returns an error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why bother with the extra variable `styles` have you tried just doing `element.css(prop, stylesOld[selector][prop])` ?

Comment: I have now :D Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript object literal syntax only supports literal keys. If you want variable keys, you have to assign the values individually instead:

```
var styles = {};
styles[prop] = stylesOld[selector][prop];
```